# jQuery: event delegation between different parents

Tags: jquery, css, events, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add a class to a dynamically added SVG element in my page, using jQuery's event delegation `.on` method similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/joum1984/jugsp8xa/2/) JSfiddle. (also not working as intended, add the circle first, then add the border)

As far as I can tell, its not working because there is no propagation of the event involving the different elements, `svg` and `button`.

My real application has a checkbox at the same DOM level as a SVG container for d3.js, and I'm trying to "filter" elements in the SVG by adding/removing a `hidden` CSS class to some dynamically added SVG elements, `.on` checkbox `change`.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: To whoever downvoted: care to explain why? I'd be happy to rephrase or correct my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah adding and removing CSS can be done via d3 like this:

```
d3.selectAll(".circle").classed("circle-border", true);
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/jugsp8xa/3/)